# Query link printing error in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a query that scans whichever URL is linked to the div class "_1gkBDw _2O43P5" and print it.

Here is the programming:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=mattress'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:/users/Asashin/Desktop/Bots/others/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

# Select language
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="language-selection__list"]/button'))).click()

# Scroll few times to load all items
for x in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300)")
    time.sleep(0.1)

# Get all links (without clicking)
a = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item"]'and contain('[@class="_1gkBDw _2O43P5"]'))))
b = driver.find_element_by_xpath()

while a==True:
    all_items= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@data-sqe="link"]')
    print(all_items)
    break
```

Here are a few problems that I've encountered:

I don't know how I can search a div class within another div class into Python/Selenium:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item"]'and contain('[@class="_1gkBDw _2O43P5"]'))))
```

Here is the result it provides:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Users/Francabicon/Desktop/Bots/click test 3.py", line 26, in <module>
    a = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item"]'and contain('[@class="_1gkBDw _2O43P5"]'))))
NameError: name 'contain' is not defined
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The element you are looking for is a `div` element with the `class`attribute `_1gkBDw _2O43P5` among the child elements of the `div` with the `col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item` attribute.

You must find `div[@ class =" col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item "]` and use the `//` syntax, which is a full search for its children(`div[@class="_1gkBDw _2O43P5"]`).

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=mattress'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:/users/Asashin/Desktop/Bots/others/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

# Select language
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="language-selection__list"]/button'))).click()

# Scroll few times to load all items
for x in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300)")
    time.sleep(0.1)

# Get all links (without clicking)
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item"]//div[@class="_1gkBDw _2O43P5"]')))

for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@data-sqe="link"]'):
    print(element)
```

Comment: Ive tried it does run but it doesn't output anything

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using `contain` instead of `contains`.

Try

```
//div[@class='hoge' and contains(@id,'huga')
```

Comment: it still doesn't work for it even if i place contains.

Comment: I've tried to create various while loops and it doesn't seem to get the URL nor it can find the class

Answer (score 0):

To get all the **URLs** which contain a `div` element with class `_1gkBDw _2O43P5`.

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and the following **XPath** expression:

> "//div[@class='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item'][.//div[@class='_1gkBDw _2O43P5']]//a[@data-sqe='link']"

---

**Code Block:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/search?keyword=mattress'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:/users/Asashin/Desktop/Bots/others/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
# Select language
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="language-selection__list"]/button'))).click()
# Scroll few times to load all items
for x in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300)")
    time.sleep(0.1)

# Get all links (without clicking) which contains div element with class `_1gkBDw _2O43P5`
alllinks = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item'][.//div[@class='_1gkBDw _2O43P5']]//a[@data-sqe='link']")))

for link in alllinks:
  # Print the href value of the anchor tag
  print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```